# Rails3 - Caching in development mode with Rails.cache.fetch

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching, activerecord

In development, the following (simplified) statement always logs a cache miss, in production it works as expected:

```
@categories = Rails.cache.fetch("categories", :expires_in => 5.minutes) do
  Rails.logger.info "+++ Cache missed +++"
  Category.all
end
```

If I change config.cache_classes from false to true in config/development.rb, it works as well in development mode, however, this makes development rather painful. Is there any configuration setting that is like `config.cache_classes = false` except that Rails.cache.fetch is fetching from cache if possible?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try placing the following in **/config/environments/development.rb**:

```
# Temporarily enable caching in development (COMMENT OUT WHEN DONE!)
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

Additionally, if your cache store configuration is in **/config/environments/production.rb**, then you will need to copy the appropriate line into **development.rb** as well. For example, if your cache store is the Dalli memcache gem:

```
# copied from production.rb into development.rb for caching in development
config.cache_store = :dalli_store, '127.0.0.1'
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Just a bonus tip, add an unless ENV["DEV_CACHE"] put the testing config in it, with an else that has the normal non-caching config in it. Then whenever you want to enable caching in your terminal, you can write export DEV_CACHE="ANYTHING". Best part is, you're way less like to accidentally have caching enabled when you don't want it.

Comment: This tip is super useful together with the solution.