# rails turning on HTTP caching for development and heroku production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, caching, heroku

I've got a rails app hosted on heroku. I'm trying to make some basic http caching, but I can't make it work in development (I've not tried in production yet). I'm not even sure if my controller code is the one I need.

How can I make this work in dev env? Are there any caveats for production?

development.rb

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

production.rb

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store,
                (ENV["MEMCACHIER_SERVERS"] || "").split(","),
                {:username => ENV["MEMCACHIER_USERNAME"],
                 :password => ENV["MEMCACHIER_PASSWORD"],
                 :failover => true,
                 :socket_timeout => 1.5,
                 :socket_failure_delay => 0.2,
                 :pool_size => ENV["MAX_THREADS"]
                }
```

static page controller

```
 def about
   expires_in 24.hours, :public => true
 end
```

response for caching:

```
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, private, max-age=0
```

Comment: Did you restart your server after changing `development.rb` ?

Comment: Yeah! I've played around with it and tried a bunch of stuff, but couldn't pull it off.

Comment: Did you look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636299/rails3-caching-in-development-mode-with-rails-cache-fetch

Comment: I tried it, but didn't help.